# How to better understand optionals

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "segueone")
    {
        let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
        if  let unwrappedCellindexPath = cellIndexPath
        {
            var nextVC = (segue.destinationViewController as TableTwo)
            nextVC.items = items[unwrappedCellindexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

With this piece of code, I have a few questions regarding the optionals.  I recently read-through the apple developer web document as well as a few personal explanations of optionals but still have question.

Anyways,

1. in the line

   ```
   let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
   ```

   Is this statement only considered to be an optional because a user may not select one of the cells in my table?  And with that, since I know that as long as a user wants to continue through the app, they must select a cell, I can place the exclamation point in to notify the compiler that this cell does in deed have a value(index path)?
2. Why does the exclamation point go after "self.tableview" and not after "sender as UITableView) in parentheses?
3. If my assuming is correct, I am able to use the `if let` syntax because I have an optional in the previous line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
```

Uses an exclamation point after `tableView`, because `self.tableView!` may not have been set (it may be `nil`).

It is an optional because it has the *option* to have a value, and it also has the *option* to be `nil`. Variables that are not optionals cannot be `nil`, they have to have a value.

The exclamation point goes after `tableView` because that is the optional which could be `nil`. If it went after `.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)`, that would imply that the value returned could be nil.

You can use the `if let` syntax because of this optional. This will return true if the value can be assigned to the variable. For example:

```
var myNilValue: String?
if(let nonNilValue = myNilValue){
    //this will not be called
}
```

`if let` will return false, but:

```
var myNonNilValue: String? = "Hello, World!"
if(let nonNilValue = myNilValue){
    //this will be called
}
```

Will return true.

Question marks `?` are used after variable declarations to define that the variable may not have a value, **and it may never have a value**. They need to be unwrapped by using an exclamation point `!` after the variable name. This can be used for results from a database, in case there is no result.

Exclamation points `!` are used after variable declarations to define that the variable may not have a value, **but it will have a value when you need to access it**. They do not need to be unwrapped, but the compiler will throw an error if the variable is `nil` at the time of accessing it. This is typically used in `@IBOutlets` or `@IBActions` which are not defined until the program compiles

Answer (score 0):

1. Both self.tableView and indexPathForCell() are optionals.  By banging one, you only have one optional to dereference in the result.  sender is also an optional and indexPathForCell() doesn't take an optional so it probably needs a bang too, but I haven't compiled it so I can't say for sure what the compiler will do.
2. self.tableView is reference to a property that might not have been set (e.g. is nil), so it is an optional. You can declare it for example an @IBOutlet with a ! at the end if you know it will ALWAYS be defined, such as from the Storyboard, and then you don't have to bang dereference it later.

A common thing to do is:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!
```

That's an implicitly unwrapped optional, and will generate an error if it's referenced when nil. But you don't need to use a ! to dereference.

3. Correct. The result of the line will produce an optional that you can test with if let

Comment: just to clarify, an ! is placed after the earliest piece of code that may be considered an optional?

Comment: also, sorry, if I included the IBOulet, which you mentioned, I would not have to include the ! in     let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)

Comment: @JonGi When you *declare* a variable, you can make it optional by adding a `?` suffix. Then it can be nil and it must be must accessed via ! *unless* you're using a `let` statement, alternatively, you can append `!`, which means *implicitly unwrapped options*. That too is an optional, meaning, Swift tolerates the value being nil, but you don't have to explicitly unwrap it later, however if it is nil at *access* time, program crashes.  You declare implicitly unwrapped optionals when you know for a fact they will be non-nil any time you *retrieve* their value.  @IBOutlet is just one example.